# Add legend to python plots

Tags: python, plot

I have this following matlab code that shows me the repartition of a feature data between two labels (0 & 1).I want to know how to add a legend on the plot with two labels : one is Phishy to orange bar and Non-Phishy to blue bar.

```
    XS = pd.value_counts(X['HTML content'])
    plt.show()
    XS.plot.bar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you're Using matplotlib

```
XS.legend()
```

Comment: I tried it and it shows the following error `Series' object has no attribute 'legend'`. When I tried plt.legend() it gives me only the blue bar legend.

Answer (score 0):

use this line of code :-

```
XS.legend()
```

Comment: Try to elaborate abit in your answers. For example give some context to this line of code. Additionally, OP asked for specific labels, I don't see that here...

Comment: I tried it and it shows the following error `Series' object has no attribute 'legend'`. When I tried plt.legend() it gives me only the blue bar legend.